# Changing flutter Navigation and status bar color in Splash Screen

Tags: android, flutter, android-splashscreen

when i use [NativeSplashScreen](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) package in android , status bar and Navigation bar backgrounds ARE NOT transparent. so it makes the ui look a bit ugly. what im trying to fidn out is that if there is a way to make them transparent?
i need this only for Android, so i expect I'll be using some platform native solution.
here are 2 pictures of how my  splash screen looks like now , and  how it should look like.

current splash screen (status and navigation bar colors are not transparent) :

[current splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nJuY.jpg)

desired splash screen :
[desired splash screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HmIr.jpg)

as you can see , in my case splash screen navigation bar and status bar background colors should be transparent.
any solution?
thx

changing flutter says and navigation bar color dosent seem to work , as splash screen is showed before flutter app runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a specific parameter for this. You may search `fullscreen: true` in the whole documentation [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash#1-setting-the-splash-screen). You must need to write that parameter in the `pubspec.yaml` file where you just wrote other code for [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash). Try & test it out. Feel free to provide acknowledgement for same.

[image]

Comment: yea,after adding some native code in styles.xml, it works. thanks.